Show that the vectors are linearly dependent.
I am completely new to linear algebra and came across the following problem:
Let $V$ be a real vector space and $a,b,c,d \in V$. Suppose that
$$v_1=a+b+c+d$$
$$v_2=2a+2b+c-d$$
$$v_3=a+b+3c-d$$
$$v_4=a-c+d$$
$$v_5=-b+c-d$$
I have to show that $(v_1,\dots,v_5)$ is linearly dependent.
I do understand that I can express any one of the vectors as a linear combination of the other four but the question says that there is also a proof in which I don't need to do any calculations.
(Source: Klaus Janich - Linear Algebra Problem 3.1)
I know that $(v_1,\dots, v_5)$ is linearly independent if the following proposition is true:
$$\sum_{i=1}^5 \lambda_i v_i=0 \implies \lambda_1 = \dots = \lambda_5=0$$
where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
For them to be linearly dependent there must be some $(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_5)$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^5\lambda_i v_i=0 \nRightarrow \lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_5=0$$
I tried clubbing the vectors together:
$a(\lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4)+b(\lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 - \lambda_5) +c(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+3\lambda_3-\lambda_4+\lambda_5)+d(\lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3+\lambda_4-\lambda_5)=0$
but I am not sure how to proceed after this nor do I know if this is the right way to go about it.

Your approach is correct. It remains to find concrete values of $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{5}$ that satisfy your final equation, equivalent to solving a system of linear equations of 5 unknowns.

Moreover, the problem of finding such $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{5}$ is called The Implicitization Problem: a particular (and simple) case is finding a system of linear equations from a given parametrization of solutions. You can find an algorithm for this case in Chapter 2, section 1 of Cox, Little & O'Shea's Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms (4th edition). This specific section of the book requires almost no background.

Notice that you have $4$ vectors and $5$ equations. Also, determinant might help if you know.

Hint (may be a bit more?) Let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $a,b,c,d$. What can you say about $\dim W$?

If I am not wrong, it would follow that $1 \leq \text{dim}(W) \leq 4$. Since $W$ is a subspace, $v_1,\dots,v_5 \in W$. The length of $(v_1, \dots, v_5)$ is 5 and since $5 > \text{dim} (W)$ it follows that $(v_1, \dots, v_5)$ is linearly dependent. Am I right?

Correct. In theory we could even have $\dim W=0$, if all the vectors $a,b,c,d$ were equal to zero.

(your method, continued): Let's find $\lambda_i$, $i=1,5$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^5 \lambda_i v_i=0$, that is
$$\lambda_1(a+b+c+d)+
\lambda_2(2a+2b+c-d)+\lambda_3(
a+b+3c-d)+
\lambda_4(a-c+d)+
\lambda_5(-b+c-d)=0$$
or
$$(\lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4)a+(\lambda_1+2\lambda_2+\lambda_3-\lambda_5)b+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+3\lambda_3-\lambda_4+\lambda_5)c+(\lambda_1 -\lambda_2-\lambda_3+\lambda_4-\lambda_5)d=0$$
We got the system in $(\lambda_i)_{i=1,5}$
$$ 
\lambda_1 + 2 \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 + 0\cdot \lambda_5= 0 \\
\lambda_1+2\lambda_2+\lambda_3+ 0\cdot \lambda_4-\lambda_5=0\\
\lambda_1+\lambda_2+3\lambda_3-\lambda_4+\lambda_5=0\\
\lambda_1 -\lambda_2-\lambda_3+\lambda_4-\lambda_5=0
$$
a system of homogenous linear equations, $4$ equations and $5$ unknowns.  The system has a non-trivial solution $(5,2,-5,-4,4)$ ( can be found in several ways, by hand, direct check, or a CAS)  and so
$$5(a+b+c+d)+2(2a+2b+c-d)+(-5)(a+b+3c-d)+(-4)(a-c+d)+4(-b+c-d)=0$$
as one can check.  We got the linear dependence.
Note: In general, a homogenous linear system of $m$ in $n$ unknowns has a non-trivial solution if $m<n$. In our case we had $m=4$ equations ( the coefficients of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$)  and $n=5$ unknowns $\lambda_i$, $i=1,5$.
